# Laravel getDirty() returning empty when it shouldn't

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Imagine an Eloquent model with properties like so:

```
class Campaign extends Eloquent
{
    protected $softDelete = true;
    protected $dates = ['started_at', 'ended_at'];
}
```

As can be inferred, the table has the standard timestamps of created_at_updated_at, and deleted_at. It also has two *date* fields: started_at and ended_at. Somewhere in the bowels of my application, I am trying to update the two extra dates:

```
$campaign->started_at = Carbon::parse(Input::get('activate-start', '+1 week'))->toDateString();
var_dump($campaign->getOriginal('started_at'), $campaign->started_at);
var_dump($campaign->getDirty());
```

The first var_dump, which compares the original to the current, shows a difference in values. However, getDirty(), returns an empty array. Because of this, `$campaign->save()` returns true without updating the DB. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was fixed by changing the $guarded property. Mine is now:

```
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
```